# Netsuite Oauth 2.0 implementation issue

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, netsuite

I have tested all the API using OAuth 2.0 in postman, but I don't have idea how I should implement via code using NodeJS

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Also which flow are you trying to use ?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/netsuite-rest could you like to help me to give a good flow,if you have please share